# Button text cut off when added dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

[image]

First 5 buttons are added programatically and last one via XML. Both ways I use same parameters. Why are dynamically added buttons text's cut off?

Programatic:

```
Button b = new Button(getActivity());
b.setText(text);
b.setAllCaps(false);
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_tag_rect);
b.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhiteText));

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        dpToPx(28));

int marginInPx = dpToPx(2);
params.setMargins(marginInPx, marginInPx, marginInPx, marginInPx);

tagCloudTwitter.addView(b, tagCloudTwitter.getChildCount()-1, params);
```

XML:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="28dp"
android:layout_margin="2dp"
android:textAllCaps="false"
android:background="@drawable/button_tag_rect"
android:textColor="@color/colorWhiteText"
android:text="test"/>
```

---

**EDIT: solved! See my answer bellow.**

Comment: I think is because the height is too short. Try make it higher and see.

Comment: That is true, but why is text not cut off for XML's button, which is the same height (28dp)? I think I am missing some flag. I tried setting Gravity to center, but didn't help.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is in `setMargins` ?

Comment: Try this, remove this line -- params.setMargins(marginInPx, marginInPx, marginInPx, marginInPx);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Funnily enough, what helped was setting a "dummy" padding:

```
b.setPadding(1,1,1,1);
```

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the button height and width;

```
 b.setWidth(10);
    b.setHeight(100);
```

Comment: Tried setting width and height - did not help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've managed to fix this; see answer below.